# Is it possible to fire Click event on button through eye tracker using python? how?

Tags: python, eye-tracking, eye-detection

I want to perform click function if user through eye tracker is looking at some position on the screen for 2 seconds I am getting position value through eye tracker and saving into a text file, but don't know how to perform click function.

Comment: Have you already got the eye-tracking software?

Comment: You could use something like pymouse and just click the position?

Comment: yes I do have a software named my gaze